# Return a file from asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, api-design

I've been trying to return a file from my web api. Below is my code somehow downloads the file, but the downloaded file is corrupted.

```
SomeMethod
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    // processing the stream.

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(response.FileArray.ToArray())
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "CertificationCard.pdf"
        };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}

public HttpResponseMessage Download([FromUri] DownloadRequest req) { }
```

Comment: How is the file being stored on your server? Is it a blob on the database and you need to convert it to a file?

Comment: Hi its stored in sharepoint. I download from it as byte array. If i try to write that byte array to a local path it writes fine and the file opens up and not corrupt. Its corrupted only when i return it through my web api

Comment: Did you inspect the resulting file in a text editor or hex viewer? Did you check to see if maybe some extra content got jammed into the beginning or end of the resulting file?

Comment: Not really. Do i need to set some contentlength or something before i send the response. Its kind of opens up but the contents are not showing up

Comment: hi guys anyone has any suggestion